# Removing pages from PDF using PDFBox produces bigger PDF than original

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I need to extract page range from PDF files.
I use the following code for this (using PDFBox v2.0.4):

```
    int startPage = 17;
    int endPage = 18;
    String fn = "original.pdf";
    String resFn = "result.pdf";
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(fn), MemoryUsageSetting.setupMixed(1024 * 1024));
    int cnt = doc.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = cnt - 1; i > endPage; i--) {
        doc.removePage(i);
    }
    for (int i = startPage - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        doc.removePage(i);
    }
    doc.save(new FileOutputStream(resFn));
```

However for relatively small original files it produces slightly larger result files.
For example an original.pdf file of 800Kb (which has 22 pages) resulted in a result.pdf file of 1300Kb (which had just 2 pages).

Can anyone tell me how make PDFBox create smaller PDF (or at least the same size as original)?

Comment: Try again with the latest version and link to the pdf.

Comment: It's possible that the PDF is using some compression types that are supported for reading but not writing by PDFBox. Without the PDF, it's hard to tell exactly what's going on.

Comment: Some PDFs use a global `/Resources` dictionary, i.e. one shared by all pages. If this is the case, then all shared resources, even if they don't appear on the chosen pages, might be in the output file (depends on how PDFBox handles this case).

Comment: Somewhat related to the 2nd comment: PDFBox can read compressed object streams but doesn't use them for writing. This can be a problem with complex PDFs, e.g. tagged PDFs.

Comment: I tested with latest version (4.0.7) and the result is the same.
It is a tagged PDF. Is there a way to force compression of all object streams when writing?

Comment: 4.0.7 doesn't exist, I assume you mean 2.0.7. No we can't force compression of object streams because PDFBox doesn't support writing object streams. An alternative is to post-process your file with qpdf.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can run [PDFDebugger](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline#pdfdebugger) on both the source and pdfbox-generated file and see if there is any obvious difference.